# Events Tickets Profit for the comany

Tags: commerce

I am trying to create an event ticketing system with drupal 7 and would like to insert the company's commission to it.
In simple explanation.
If event planner ticket price is $x 
Company commission rate is 15%

The planner to choose whether the customers pay for the commission + ticket or the planner pays upfront.

Is there any module that support something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a pct fee on top of your order, you've got a couple of options, the quick and dirty one is to create a fake tax of the percentage you want, see http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/tax-configuration, another option is to multiply the amount by 0.15 or whatever quantity on the rules event you choose.

For fixed fees you can check [Commerce Fees](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fees)

You've got also [commerce discount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) and [commerce coupon](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) that do the exact opposite operation, so you can check how to add and modify stuff in the checkout, if you're looking for a more advanced solution.